# Split 3D Carousel Image Rotation Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios

I found a carousel (https://codepen.io/paulnoble/pen/yVyQxv) that has some awesome transitions and thought it'd be nice to integrate into a project I'm working on: https://joshrodg.com/halloffame/

My code is here: https://codepen.io/joshrodgers/pen/MWBPXBx

The responsiveness of the design needed to be adjusted slightly because to me having the content split (left, right) doesn't quite work that well on smaller screens (like phones) - it'd make it almost impossible to read. So, my idea was just to remove the right-side content all together.

I have that working and it looks exactly as I expect, except one thing...

Basically, there is vertical paging on the right-side of the slideshow. When you click on the next circle it rotates forward to the next slide, when you click on the previous circle, it rotates backwards to the previous slide. On a desktop screen (larger than 900px) the paging area stays on top of the rotating images, which makes the slideshow rotation look really nice. On my iPhone, and I'm guessing on other small screens, the rotating images appear to rotate on top of the paging area and then it re-appears.

I'm sure this is a simple tweak, but is there a way to keep the paging area on top while rotating through the images on a desktop and smaller screen like an iPhone?

This is also an issue on the original carousel, so I'm not sure how to fix it.

The paging area does have a `z-index: 1` but for some reason the images still rotate on top of the paging area. I even tried setting it higher: `z-index: 1000`, but that didn't seem to do anything.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into this a little more, I was able to find a solution!

My `carousel__control` div is what was controlling the vertical pagination, this was in `carousel` container and rightfully so, as it was controlling the position of everything inside. However, this also caused the issues I described, not really sure why.

All I did to fix this was move `carousel__control` out of the `carousel` container - basically right above it in the document. Then had to set my margins to match and adjust it's position. I couldn't keep the `margin: auto` and `top: 0`. Once I adjusted those two properties, everything started working as expected.

I have updated the pen here: https://codepen.io/joshrodgers/pen/MWBPXBx

Thanks,
Josh